# Material-UI: How do I resolve "Warning: Prop `id` did not match"

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, server-side-rendering, next.js

I have a basic react app that lists a number of employees. I'm receiving the following console warning:

> Warning: Prop `id` did not match. Server:
>   "undefined-Searchforanemployee-undefined-57040" Client:
>   "undefined-Searchforanemployee-undefined-41361"

The employee list is filterable via a Material-UI `TextField` component, which looks like this:

```
<TextField
  hintText='Search for an employee'
  onChange={(e, value) => { this.filterEmployeesList(value) }}
/>
```

If I delete the `TextField` component, the warning disappears, so it clearly has something to do with the issue.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Can you also share your employee list?

Answer (score 4):

The fix is dead simple. Add an `id` attribute to the `TextField` component:

```
<TextField
  id='employee-search'
  hintText='Search for an employee'
  onChange={(e, value) => { this.filterEmployeesList(value) }}
/>
```

Comment: A little explanation would be great.